# cordova custom datepicker plugin display only years

Tags: cordova, datepicker, cordova-plugins

I am facing issue with setting custom date for the cordova date picker plugin `cordova-plugin-datepicker` in my cordova project. this below code is working properly . But I want to display only years I tried to change mode date into year but is doesn't work .. how can I display only years? Could you please help.

```
var options = {
  date: new Date(),
  maxDate:  Date.parse(new Date()),
  androidTheme: 4 , 
  mode: 'date' //'year' not working 
};

function onSuccess(date) {
  var curr_date = date.getDate();
  var curr_month = date.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  var curr_year = date.getFullYear();
  var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year ;
  $("#purchaseDate").val(formattedDate);
}

function onError(error) {}

datePicker.show(options, onSuccess, onError);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ready the documentation of that plugin [cordova-plugin-datepicker](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) seems that is not possible to obtain what you want. The only supported modes are:

- date
- time
- datetime (only for iOS and Windows)

If you want to achieve your goal in a native way you have to extend that plugin or create a new one. Another cordova plugin which could fit your use case case is [cordova-wheel-selector-plugin](https://github.com/jasonmamy/cordova-wheel-selector-plugin). Generally you don't need a date picker but a number one since you have to select just the years.

If you don't want or you are not able to work on a cordova plugin or the other one does't help you you could use `js` and `HTML` to create a custom date picker. You could find some example on the ionic market or github:

- [ion number picker](https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ion-number-picker)
- [Mobiscroll Date & Time](https://market.ionic.io/plugins/mobiscroll-mobile-date-and-time-picker)
- [Proton: Multi List Picker](https://market.ionic.io/plugins/multi-list-picker)
- [Ion-Multi-Picker](https://github.com/raychenfj/ion-multi-picker)

Comment: thnx for reply tell me another way how i achieve this i dont know how to create custom plugin :(

Comment: yeah i got it thanx alot :)

Comment: "this" `cordova-wheel-selector-plugin` looks awesome, thanks!